# APScheduler run a job for a specific amount of times

Tags: python-3.6, apscheduler

Python 3.6.0
APScheduler 3.3.1

I have a program that I have just modified to implement APScheduler.

The program is working exactly as intended.

Here is the code snippet where I added in APScheduler:

```
def main():
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.start()
    sched.add_job(errordetect)
    sched.add_job(errordetect, 'interval', minutes=5)
    input("Press enter to exit.")
```

The job runs 'right now' and then every 5 minutes.  My issue is this:
I have to stop the job manually by pressing 'Enter'.

Is there a way to say either:
    1) Stop running after X amount of time (say one hour) or
    2) stop after X iterations (say twelve iterations)

What I am wanting is to run the job every 5 minutes for one hour, so I
want it to stop on it's own after twelve iterations (or one hour -- effectively the same thing).  I am not finding anything like that in the documentation, but I am hoping that I am either missing something in the docs or that there is another way to accomplish what I am after.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
x = 0
starttime = time.time()
while x < 5:
    i = 0
    for a_connection in ssh_conns:
        errordetect(a_connection, ip_addrs[i])
        i += 1
    x += 1
    if x == 5:
        break
    time.sleep(15.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 15.0))
```